# Unity 3D: Load sprites from a folder

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, sprite-sheet

Is it possible in Unity 3D using C# to create an array to load sprites randomly from a *folder* rather than from a sprite sheet?  If it is, what code do I use to refer to the folder?  From what I can find, sprites are usually coded to load using random.range with an array using a sprite sheet instead of actually accessing the folder.  The only thing even similar to this that I have been able to find is here:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html

but as you can see with this you can only load from a folder titled "Resources" in the "Assets" folder, and possibly I'm mistaken but it would also seem that this can only be done with a game object. (?)

Comment: A bit more specifically, you should look at [`Resouces.Load`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html). You can load from *any* asset folder named `Resources` in your Unity project. If you want to load from some arbitrary location when the game is running that's another story--check out [Loading texture file from png/jpg file on disk](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/432655/loading-texture-file-from-pngjpg-file-on-disk.html) on Unity answers. (Either way I think you should edit the question for clarity!)

Comment: Thanks all!  I got it to work with this:  

Sprite[] enemySprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Sprites/Enemies");

Comment: @Veniversum You can answer your own question by adding an answer below. This makes it easier for others to find your solution.

Comment: Ok, thank you; it's only like my second time ever posting here.  I appreciate the tip

Answer (score 4):

You are looking at the right docs.

A sprite is a GameObject, just a more specific one meant to be used in 2d games. So you would create your sprites and make prefab of them. Those prefabs go in the Resources folder and here is the code:

```
GameObject [] objs = (GameObject[])Resources.LoadAll("SpriteFolder");
GameObject randomSprite = objs[Random.Range(0, objs.Length)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up using:

Sprite[] enemySprites = Resources.LoadAll("Sprites/Enemies");